# Laravel - Recursive relationships without some data

Tags: laravel, recursion, eloquent, relation

I'm working with 3 Models which are Panel, Item and PanelContent.
PanelContent has 3 properties :

- parent_id (who is a Panel)
- contentable_id (who is a Panel or Item)
- contentable_type (define if the child is a Panel or Item)

I want to loop recursively my relationships to get my data as a tree. To do this, I write these functions :

PanelContent :

```
public function contentable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function contentables()
{
    return $this->contentable()->with('allContents');
}
```

Panel :

```
public function contents(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(PanelContent::class, 'parent_id')->orderBy('order');
}

public function allContents()
{
    return $this->contents()->with('contentables');
}
```

When I call "allContents", it's working, but I have some data I don't want to keep.

```
dd($parentPanel->allContents->toArray());
```

Give me this results :

[image]

Here, I have all the data for Panel, Item and PanelContent, but I don't want to get PanelContent data, this is juste a table to set all relations between Panel and Item.

Do you have an idea to keep only Panel and Item data even if I use PanelContent for the relation ?

Thank you so much, have a nice evening.

Comment: I am also looking for the same functionality. In cakePHP you could define the level of recursion that you could have in the query, now I need to do the same in Laravel, so that it brings me a query without relations that I don't need, to optimize the time of the same.